# array count doesn't show correct number, rather just "1"

Tags: count

I have several John Jones with different names in a form. I submit the form to another program which uses "$checkednames = implode(', ', $_POST['raters']);". I echo $checkednames and see all the names but "count($checkednames)" is 1 and not the number of names. What could be wrong?

I appreciate any help.

You may seen the results by going to:

www.golfcourseratingassistant.org/ratecourse/

select Course name > Select Tee Box > Course Data ...select for all lists then "Save Data".

Selected data is only valid for the current session.

Answer (score 1):

It will be 1 only, *implode()* returns a string containing a string representation of all the array elements in the same order, with the glue string between each element. See [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
explode() will return an array of strings
```

So count() after explode() will give you the number of elements.

You can see the names because it is one string.

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo count($comma_separated);// Output will be 1
```

For explode():

```
$string= "lastname,email,phone";
$array= explode(",", $string);

echo count($array); //output will be 3
```